# Scala Implicit Conversion for companion object of extended class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, implicit-conversion, companion-object

I am trying to create a customRDD in Java.

RDD converts `RDD[(K,V)]` to `PairRDDFunctions[K,V]` using Scala implicit function `rddToPairRDDFunctions()` defined in `object RDD`.

I am trying to do the same with my `CustomJavaRDD` which extends `CustomRDD` which extends `RDD`.

Now it should call implicit function `rddToCustomJavaRDDFunctions()` whenever it encounters `CustomJavaRDD[(K,V)]`, but for some reason it still goes to `rddToPairRDDFunctions()`.

What am I doing wrong?

*RDD.scala*

```
class RDD[T]
object RDD {
  implicit def rddToPairRDDFunctions[K, V](rdd: RDD[(K, V)])
      (implicit kt: ClassTag[K], vt: ClassTag[V], ord: Ordering[K] = null):
      PairRDDFunctions[K, V] = {
    new PairRDDFunctions(rdd)
  }
}
```

*CustomRDD.scala*

```
abstract class CustomRDD[T] extends RDD[T]
object CustomRDD {
  implicit def rddToCustomJavaRDDFunctions[K,V](rdd: CustomJavaRDD[(K,V)]): 
      PairCustomJavaRDDFunction[K,V] = {
    new PairCustomJavaRDDFunctions[K,V](rdd)
  }
}
```

*PairCustomJavaRDDFunctions.scala*

```
class PairCustomJavaRDDFunctions[K: ClassTag, V: ClassTag](self: CustomRDD[(K, V)])
                        (implicit ord: Ordering[K] = null) {
  def collectAsMap() = ???
}
```

There is no error; the program compiles successfully,
but let's say I have `data: RDD` which is an instance of `CustomJavaRDD`.

```
data.collectAsMap()
```

At the runtime it converts `data` into `PairRDDFunctions`; i.e. it makes implicit call to `rddToPairRDDFunctions` defined in *RDD.scala*.

But it should make call to `rddToCustomJavaRDDFunctions` defined in *CustomRDD.scala* and convert it into `PairCustomJavaRDDFunctions`.

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: What is the static type of `data` in your program? Where (and how) is it defined?

Comment: It will be defined in Java file as CustomJavaRDD data = new CustomJavaRDD(loadData("/tmp/data.txt"))

Comment: But you call `data.collectAsMap()` from scala?

Comment: Is `CustomJavaRDD` a subclass of `CustomRDD`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it should make call to `rddToCustomJavaRDDFunctions` defined in *CustomRDD.scala* and convert it into `PairCustomJavaRDDFunctions`

No, Scala simply does not work this way. What you want, overriding an implicit conversion depending on the runtime type of an object, is simply not possible (without pre-existing machinery on both the library's part and yours).

Implicits are a strictly *compile-time* feature. When the compiler sees you using an `RDD` as if it were a `PairRDDFunctions`, it splices in a call to `RDD.rddToPairRDDFunctions`, as if you wrote it yourself. Then, when the code is translated to bytecode, that call has already been baked in and *nothing can change it*. There is no dynamic dispatch for this, it's all static. The only situation where `rddToCustomJavaRDDFunctions` will be called is when the *static* type of the expression in question is already `CustomJavaRDD`.

Really, this should not be necessary. Implicit conversions are really no more than glorified helper methods that save you keystrokes. (Implicit *parameters*, now those are interesting. ;) ) There should be no need to override them because the helper methods should already be polymorphic and work whether you have `RDD`, `CustomRDD`, or `` `RDD that travels through time to compute things faster` ``.

Of course, you *can* still do it, but it will only actually do anything under the above conditions, and that is probably not very likely, making the whole thing rather pointless.